# postgres select into another table and return new tables results as json

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to copy data from one table to another that fulfils a criteria.

If I run my function it only returns one row of data instead of the 3 it should.

However if I run the INSERT command separately it correctly copies all the data to the new table (3 rows). When I run the RETURN QUERY SELECT separately it correctly returns 3 rows.

Is this a race condition please?

Please note _ref_date is ignored and I'm using hardcoded dates to debug.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION new_table(
    _ref_date timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE)
    RETURNS table (j json)
AS $$
    BEGIN
        
    INSERT INTO new_table
    (
      LASTUPDATED_BY,
      LASTUPDATED_ON,
      QTY
    )
      SELECT 
        updated_by,
        lastupdated_on,
        qty
      FROM
        old_table
      WHERE
      lastupdated_on >= '2023-05-24 00:00:00+00'
      AND
      lastupdated_on < '2023-05-27 00:00:00+00';
      
RETURN QUERY SELECT row_to_json(bod) FROM (
    SELECT * FROM new_table) bod;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may have been some caching issue in pgadmin as having dropped the function and recreated it I am getting the right results.